# Display two divs in a single line filling space - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two divs `diva` and `divb`. They have a fixed height of `30px`. I want to display them in a single line, one after the other. This can be done by giving them widths of `10%` and `90%` respectively and by `float: left`. This works fine. But I gave them a border of `1 px` and this disturbs the calculation. I gave the second div a width of `88%` and is working. But there is an empty space after that div.

I want both the divs to display in a single line. The page re sizes and I want divs to fill space and so that I can't give them fixed width. The first div may be given a fixed width, because I just want it `150 px` wide. But the second div must be wider to fill space.

What I am getting is this;

[image: Current layout]

and I want this:

[image: Expected layout]

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/76Raj/)** is the fiddle.

Comment: Ckeck [this article](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) and try to use position: absolute, "margin" or "left"

Comment: border is actually adding you 2px(1px left + 1px right) on every div

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a `width: 100%` to the body and specify `float: left;` on div1 and remove the `float: left;` on the div2.

If you're using percentage widths or heights on child elements you have to specify a percentage width or height on the parent or rather container element as well.

That should fix it! :)

[See this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/76Raj/3/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
 body{
     margin: 0;
 }
 #div1{
     height: 30px;
     width: 10%;
     outline: solid 1px #000000;
     background-color: #0066CC;
     float: left;
 }
 #div2{
     height: 30px;
     width: 90%;
     outline: solid 1px #000000;
     background-color: #66CC00;
     float: left;
 }​
```

Not so great for IE though

Comment: Did the trick for Firefox in ASP.NET page. Both "float: left".

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/J7mJX/1/

just add

```
#div1, #div2 {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;  
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;  
    box-sizing: border-box;   
}
```

so the border is included on width calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Set box-sizing:border-box; on the floated divs with % widths.

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can add extra divs that wont affect the width of the parent div with the added border

http://jsfiddle.net/ollie/76Raj/9/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="display:table">
    <div style="display: inline-block;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;">DIV 1</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:green;">DIV 2</div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:blue;">DIV 3</div>
</div>
```