# Proper Aligning of two divs on a single line in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to duplicate something similar to a windows form toolbar in html.  I've created an example of what I am currently working with.  Seems great, but when I load it into IE7 the buttons end up going to the next line.

The only other way I can think of is use a table with two columns and text-align the second column.  Anyone have any suggestions?

http://jsfiddle.net/nyEw7/

Seems like this question was already asked. I am looking for IE7 workarounds.

[Display two divs in a single line filling space - CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191228/display-two-divs-in-a-single-line-filling-space-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use float: left/right. Here's an updated jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nyEw7/1/